# How HTTPSession is maintained in cluster of servers

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am trying to understand how the `session` details are maintained for a JavaEE based web application that is deployed in a cluster of servers. I am new to clustering concepts so I am not clear on how it actually works.

I have gone through this SO post ["How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading?rq=1), where it says that the `session` details are maintained by the server where my web application is running and client is provided with `JSESSIONID`. Now suppose if I have a load balancer and my application is deployed to a cluster of servers say 3 servers, now if my first request is handled by Server1 and the Server1 has stored the `session` details on its RAM, then what happens to my subsequent request? Will load balancer still direct the request to Server1 or will it be handled by Server2/Server3?

Comment: It will be rely on the implementation of the application server.
Tomcat 6 can use a shared file system, shared data base or a in memory with a TCP protocol with "automagical" propagation. More here: 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Overview

Comment: More Tomcat info here: http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2013-02-Apache-Tomcat-Clustering.pdf